# How to remove decimal point in DataStage?

Tags: sql, netezza, datastage

I would like to remove the decimal point from the column.

For example, D21.3 would become D213

Someone help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataStage 9.1  or above, try:

```
Ereplace(ColumnName, ".", "")
```

Comment: Thank you, Khan, It is working now. How to do the same transformation in Netezza?

Answer (score 0):

In Netezza

```
=> select translate('D21.3','.','');
 TRANSLATE
-----------
 D213
```